# Systemd on Ubuntu 16.04 gives no such interface error

Tags: systemd

I'm now trying to deploy my Phoenix(Elixir) application in Ubuntu 16.04. For persistency, I'm using this file (app.service) in /lib/systemd/system.

```
[Unit]
Description=Runner for My Phoenix App

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/app
Environment=MIX_ENV=prod PORT=4000
ExecStart=/app/bin/app start
ExecStop=/app/bin/app stop
User=mohideen
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My username is `mohideen` and the account has sudo rights. When I try to use the command `sudo systemctl start app.service`, the command fails with the following error:

```
Failed to start app.service: Unknown unit: app.service
See system logs and 'systemctl status app.service' for details.
```

When I type `sudo systemctl status app.service`, I get this message:

```
Failed to get properties: No such interface ''
```

The app works fine when I start it manually. Why am I getting this error? How can I ensure that my application gets restarted on reboot and crash?

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related sites http://unix.stackexchange.com (Unix & Linux) or http://superuser.com . Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Are you sure `/lib/systemd/system` is the correct place to put .service files in your OS? As far as I know, in Ubuntu 16.04, they should be in `/etc/systemd/system`. Also try running `systemctl daemon-reload` before running `start` or `status`.

Answer (score 4):

There were two reasons for my problem.

Firstly, my `.service` file location was wrong. It should be `/etc` and not `/lib`.

Secondly, `upstart` was installed earlier by me. This prevents `.service` files from running (I don't know why). Once I uninstalled `upstart` and re-installed `systemd`, the problem was solved!